# What angle does the sun have to shine for shade balls to shade 100%

Tags: geometry

Shade balls are plastic spheres that can be placed on the surface of a water reservoir to reduce the amount of sunlight hitting the reservoir.

These spheres when packed tightly can cover almost 91% of the surface of the reservoir:

https://youtu.be/BZbChKzedEk?t=242

The math checks out:

$$ \frac{2 \sqrt3}{\pi} \approx 0.9069 $$

But that assumes that the sun is directly overhead. If the sun is lower in the sky, presumably it gets closer to 100%. 
What is the smallest angle of incidence that the sun has to shine where a single layer of tightly packed shade balls can shade 100% of the water's surface?

Comment: Do you mean the sunlight shouldn't hit the surface, or the sunlight shouldn't reach below the balls? Granted, with refraction, those are almost the same, and one becomes very difficult to calculate, and basically impossible in case the water isn't perfectly still, but it doesn't hurt to be specific.

Comment: Great question. I'm assuming an idealized reservoir. So ignoring refraction and assuming still water. 
I guess I mean the ray of sunlight shouldn't reach below the balls, but assume one or the other if the math comes out easier.

Comment: It is assumed the worst case orientation of the balls tightly packed? This is the angle that goes exactly between the two opposite side 2 balls?

Comment: You can assume the best case orientation. That's why I wrote "can" in 
"where a single layer of tightly packed shade balls can shade 100% of the water's surface"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an idealised situation, the balls are arranged as in the image below (view from above). If the Sun shines from "due south", the blue ball's shadow must cover the gap north of its northern neighbours as indicated - because no other ball can as easily.

The read triangle shows the situation from the side (i.e., the hypotenuse is the water line, the long leg is the shadow boundary).
We readily read off the length of the hypotenuse as $2\sqrt 3-1$ times the ball radius. Hence the angle at the top vertex (which corresponds to the elevation angle of the point-sized Sun) is
$$\arcsin\frac1{2\sqrt 3-1} \approx 23.9^\circ$$

[image]

However, I am not yet totally sure about other Sun directions (or lattice rotations) - thus if the reference were to a differnet Youtube channel, the above image might need to be called a Parker shadow ...

Comment: The Parker shadow! nice!